# Symfony2 Routing: Two optional parameters - at least one required

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I'm trying to set up some routes in symfony2 for the following pattern:

```
www.myaweseomesite.com/payment/customer/{customernumber}/{invoicenumber}
```

Both parameters are optional - so the following scenarios must work:

```
www.myaweseomesite.com/payment/customer/{customerNumber}/{invoiceNumber}
www.myaweseomesite.com/payment/customer/{customerNumber}
www.myaweseomesite.com/payment/customer/{invoiceNumber}
```

I set up my routing.yml according to the [symfony2 doc](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/routing.html).

```
payment_route:
pattern:  /payment/customer/{customerNumber}/{invoiceNumber}
defaults: { _controller: PaymentBundle:Index:payment, customerNumber: null,  invoiceNumber: null }
requirements:
    _method:  GET
```

This works great so far. The problem is, that if both parameters are missing or empty, the route should not work. So

```
www.myaweseomesite.com/payment/customer/
```

should not work. Is there any way to do this with Symfony2?

Comment: How does the params look like? Do they have length specificity or just digits ? Just letters? Letters and digits? Because if they are both of any length with only digits this is impossible, since you can't know which is which.

Comment: customerNumber is a digit, invoiceNumber is a string

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can define it in two routes to be sure to have only 1 slash.

```
payment_route_1:
    pattern:  /payment/customer/{customerNumber}/{invoiceNumber}
    defaults: { _controller: PaymentBundle:Index:payment, invoiceNumber: null }
    requirements:
        customerNumber: \d+
        invoiceNumber: \w+
        _method:  GET

payment_route_2:
    pattern:  /payment/customer/{invoiceNumber}
    defaults: { _controller: PaymentBundle:Index:payment, customerNumber: null }
    requirements:
        invoiceNumber: \w+
        _method:  GET
```

Please note that you might have to change the regex defining the parameters depending of your exact needs. You can [look at this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-requirements). Complex regex have to be surrounded by `"`. (Example `myvar : "[A-Z]{2,20}"`)

Comment: @marty glad I could help! To give a bit more info, the first route matches your 2 first types. And the second one the third type. (oops I forgot to removed the `customerNumber: null` from the first route,  else it will accept the route without any parameters. I've updated to reflect that!)

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on @Hugo answer, please find below the config with annotations :

```
/**
 * @Route("/public/edit_post/{post_slug}", name="edit_post")
 * @Route("/public/create_post/{root_category_slug}", name="create_post", requirements={"root_category_slug" = "feedback|forum|blog|"})
 * @ParamConverter("rootCategory", class="AppBundle:Social\PostCategory", options={"mapping" : {"root_category_slug" = "slug"}})
 * @ParamConverter("post", class="AppBundle:Social\Post", options={"mapping" : {"post_slug" = "slug"}})
 * @Method({"PUT", "GET"})
 * @param Request $request
 * @param PostCategory $rootCategory
 * @param Post $post
 * @return array|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
 */
public function editPostAction(Request $request, PostCategory $rootCategory = null, Post $post = null)
{ Your Stuff }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/optional_placeholders.html

set a default value for optional parameters in the annotations in the controller:

```
/**
* @Route("/blog/{page}", defaults={"page" = 1})
*/
public function indexAction($page)
{
   // ...
}
```

This way you only need one route in routing.yml